# Using proxy with undetected_webdriver in Python not working

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I am trying to use proxies in `undetected_webdriver` module but it is not working. It worked for me before with `selenium` using the following method:

```py
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
        "httpProxy": self.proxy,
        "ftpProxy": self.proxy,
        "sslProxy": self.proxy,
        "noProxy": None,
        "proxyType": "MANUAL",
        "class": "org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
        "autodetect": False
    }
```

when I try this with `undetected_webdriver` and see the website [whatismyip](https://www.whatismyip.com/) my ip still the same. I went with `Proxy` class and the issue was still the same.

Is there a way to make it happen with `undetected_webdriver`?